# Long click in Python

Tags: android, python, automation, appium

I need a method allows long click on the "password" space, as it has an "eye" on the same line, but unable to find out separate ID. but the program I wrote not doing a long click. Please correct my code:

```
def testDevice1(self):
    time.sleep(5)


    username=self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.eas.android:id/front_edit')
    username.send_keys('1@eight.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.eas.android:id/password')
    password.send_keys('111111')
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.longClick('com.eas.android:id/password')
    time.sleep(10)
    self.driver.save_screenshot('/home/nat/PycharmProjects/touchoneautomation/appiumTests/screenshots/shot1.png')
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.eas.android:id/btn_login').click()
    self.driver.save_screenshot('/home/nat/PycharmProjects/touchoneautomation/appiumTests/screenshots/shot1.1.png')
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.save_screenshot('/home/nat/PycharmProjects/touchoneautomation/appiumTests/screenshots/shot1.2.png')
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.eas.android:id/panel_logout").click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Python) look up TouchAction. you can string commands together:

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
ta = TouchAction(driver)
ta.press(x=x, y=y).release().perform()

# some_web_obj = driver.find...
ta.press(some_web_obj).wait(duration_in_millisec).release().perform()
```